# Silencing unused variable warning in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

My typescript compiler keeps complaining about unused variables. In C, I would use

```
void foo(int bar)
{
    (void)bar;
}
```

Is there a JavaScript equivalent?

Comment: `return bar-bar;`? *Note, I have no experience with javascript or typescript.*

Comment: Better question: What's the need of an unused variables? And why return 0?

Comment: The unused variable is used by a decorator.

Comment: @johannchopin A common use case for unused arguments or fixed return value is a function that is specified as an interface but not required or not possible for a specific implementation.

Comment: Can you simply use `bar;`, or does that warn too?

Comment: Just tried `bar;` and it works. Just concerned, would `bar;` evaluate it once more, leading to a performance penalty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the TSConfig file you can set `"no-unused-variable": true` that will make it stop complain about all the unused variables in the entire project

You can also put an underscore before the variable name if you want TS to ignore only that specific unused variable like this:

```
function foo(_bar:number) {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this. It's not a satisfactory approach.

Comment: you can also use _ before the variable name to make TS ignore that specific unused variable

Comment: Elegant! Wasn't aware of `_`, definitely going with this.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat ugly, but fully functional way, is to simply use the variable for something.

Don't know much about Typescript, but this silences warnings in C:

```
void foo()
{
    int dummy=42;
    int x=dummy;
    dummy = x;
}
```

I guess you could use something similar.

Or as Luke_ pointed out in comments, you can give the variable a name that starts with `_`

Comment: a better way would be to start the variable name with _, this will silent the unused error